# POST data not submitting

Tags: php, forms, methods

I have a simple login form on a new project that doesn't submit anything.  If I `var_dump` the `$_POST` data it's empty.  If I `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` it prints GET.  If I `var_dump $_GET` it is also empty.  Can't work out what's going on, never seen this before.  Anyone have any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="login">
<div class="title">Sign In</div>
    <form id="crewlogin" method="POST" action="auth/auth.php">
        <input id="acc_number" name="acc_number" type="number" placeholder="Acc Number">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

auth.php (just some debug code at the moment to try to figure out what's happening.

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

Produces:

```
GET

array(0) {

}

array(0) {

}
```

Comment: This may sound stupid, but is `auth.php` in the `auth` directory?

Comment: also, how are you var_dumping the data in auth.php? if you're just going to that page, the POST information is lost. you will need to return it to the HTML page, or test using GET directly on auth.php

Comment: Your code is fine I checked it on my server, make sure `auth.php` is in the `auth` directory like @Tushar said.

Comment: This should work fine. Since you are getting the request method is get, then my assumption is that you aren't submitting the from in proper way. open the page with your server opened. And try submitting possiblly clearing cache. If then it do not work try it in a live server.

Comment: Clearing the cache fixed it.  Thanks.